# Send All Jenkins jobs build logs to central place and analyze the logs with key word match in automated way to mark it as either code issue etc

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

** I need a process to Send All Jenkins jobs build logs to central place and analyze the logs with key word match in automated way to mark it as either code issue or infra issue etc **

Please let me know is there way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably push your Jenkins logs to something like ELK(Elastic search, Logstash, Kibana) and then configure Alerts based on keywords you like. There are many resources available on the internet as to how to configure this. One way is to use the [Logstash Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/logstash/)